# sending emails via smtp from a server installed as IaaS in azure

Tags: azure, email, smtp, integration, sendgrid

i have many application servers (cyber-ark, SIEM solution, forti gate etc') installed on azure as a IaaS.

all of them connect to an smtp server in order to send notifications via mail.

on my on Prem deployments, this was not an issue, but on azure, all smtp communication seems to be blocked.

i created a send-grid account and tried playing with it, but the send grid smtp server is getting blocked too.

what is the right way to work in this scenario ?

i need a smtp server to integrate with my applications...
what should i do ?

thanks,
david

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your type of subscription, pay-as-you-go if you want the ability to send email from Azure VMs directly to external email providers (not using an authenticated SMTP relay), you can make a request to remove the restriction. Requests will be reviewed and approved at Microsoft's discretion, and they'll be granted only after additional anti-fraud checks are made. To make a request, open a support case by using the following issue type: Technical > Virtual Network > Connectivity > Cannot send email (SMTP/Port 25). Make sure that you add details about why your deployment has to send mail directly to mail providers instead of using an authenticated relay. [More details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity)

Comment: hi, what is an authenticated relay ? sendgrid is not an authenticated relay ?

Comment: Yes SendGrid is a SMTP relay, you are using a user/password to send e-mails outside Azure, in case your SendGrid test was on port 25 I would say that Azure VM has no connectivity on port 25, that's why you have to open a ticket to Microsoft. Please take a look at [SendGrid doc](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-smtp/) for details how it works.